# Two row vectors and their determinant

Tags: matrices, vectors

I have two row vectors: [2 2] and [2 -2] and I need to compute determinant of these to see whether they are independent or dependent, i.e if determinant is not equal to zero they will be independent.

To compute the determinant I will need to have square matrix. Can we transpose these in to column vectors and make 2x2 matrix which would allow me to find determinant? i.e 
2 2
2 -2 equals -8

Thank you

Comment: The answer is **yes**.  You can do that.  In fact, you don't even need to transpose the vectors to make a matrix out of them -- You'll get the same determinant either way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to transpose them, you can also write the matrix of columns. Since $\det(A) = \det(A^T)$, both give you the same result.

The result, in your case, is $8$, so the vectors are linearly independent.

Their independence is fairly obvious, since $\alpha [2,2] +\beta[2,-2] = 0$ means that $$2(\alpha + \beta) = 0\\ 2(\alpha - beta) = 0$$

So if you sum the two equations, you get $4\alpha = 0$, meaning that $\alpha = 0$ and then, from $2(\alpha + \beta) = 0$, you get $\beta = 0$, so you can conclude the two vectors are independent.